# UK Retail Return & Refund Regulations

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection

I bought a washer/dryer from a UK retailer.

I considered it defective and one day after purchase tried to return it to the retailer.

The retailer said it would not accept the return because the item was now "used."

Are there any laws that require the retailer to accept a return within that period?

Comment: Consumer protection regulation is vastly different around the world, even between neighbouring countries.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: I am from the UK

Comment: Did you buy it online, or did you walk into a store?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Consumer Rights Act 2015, depending on the contract and the problem. Ask your lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

The seller has to accept the return if they advertised that they would accept it. If the product was faulty, then the seller is responsible for fixing it. If you say "I consider it defective", that means nothing. If it *is* defective, that means something.